# how to use mat-checkbox to go in another component

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I want to use mat-checkbox in my project for to go in another component. Now the problem is, when I click mat-checkbox this not stay checked, only go in another page.

I tried this code.

Component 1.

html code:

```
  <div class="row col s12">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <p>Sort:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
      <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="getallevents()">Get all events:</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr>
  <div ngFor="let item of events">
     {{item.id}}
     {{item.name}}
  </div>
```

Ts Code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.events= this.service.getData();
  }
  public getallevents() {
    this.router.navigate(['/main/all_events_acted0/']);
  }
```

Component2:

html code:

```
  <div class="row col s12">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
      <p>Sort:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (click)="getallevents0()">Get All events by 0:</mat-checkbox>
      </div>

  </div>
<hr>
  <div ngFor="let item of getalleventsby0">
     {{item.id_events}}
     {{item.name_events}}
     {{item.type_events}}
  </div>
```

Ts code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getalleventsby0= this.service.getData();
  }
  public getallevents0() {
    this.router.navigate(['/main/getallevents0/']);
  }
```

When I click checkbox I want to go in another component, also I want to stay checked this checkbox. Please any idea?

Comment: ngrx which is redux philopshy

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to the new component, the first one (which has the checkboxes) is destroyed, so the state is lost.

A possible solution is to use a central state manager (I.e. [redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/store)) so that you can store the state of your checkbox even after you navigate away from the component.

A more lightweight solution is to create a service that stores the state just for that component.